# Return entire data if parameter in null in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation here, i want to select all the data from the table if my parameter is null, else it should work based on the condition,

```
SELECT 
    CA.ContactAddressId,
    CA.CompanyName AS CompanyName,
    CA.ContactPerson AS ContactPerson,
    CA.Address1 AS Street,
    ISNULL(CA.Address2,'') AS Street2,
    CA.City,
    CA.[State] AS [State],
    CA.Country AS CountryCode,
    CASE
        WHEN CA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'
        WHEN CA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'
        WHEN CA.Country = 4 THEN 'MEXICO'
    END AS Country,
    CA.ZipCode,
    CA.WorkPhone AS Phone,
    CA.WorkPhoneExt AS Ext,
    ISNULL(CA.Fax,'') AS Fax,
    CA.Email AS [Email],
    CA.AddressType,
    CA.AddressCode,
    CADS.PickupReadyTime AS PickupReadyTime,
    CADS.PickupCloseTime AS PickupCloseTime,
    CADS.DeliveryReadyTime AS DeliveryOpeningTime,
    CADS.DeliveryCloseTime AS DeliveryClosingTime,
    CAST(ISNULL(CAD.ContactAddressId,0) as bit) IsDefault
INTO #ContactAddressDetails
FROM CR2.ContactAddress AS CA WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #ContactGroupList list
    ON list.ContactGroupId = CA.ContactGroupId
LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefaultSettings AS CADS WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON CADS.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId
LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefault CAD WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON CAD.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId 
    AND CAD.UserId = @LoggedInUserId 
    --and CAD.DefaultAddressType = @DefaultAddressType
 WHERE (@ZipCodeOrigin IS Null Or CA.ZipCode IN (@ZipCodeOrigin,@ZipCodeDestination)) 
   AND (@ZipCodeDestination Is Null OR CA.ZipCode IN(@ZipCodeOrigin,@ZipCodeDestination))
```

Here @ZipCodeOrigin and @ZipCodeDestination are the parameters, if they are null i must get all the data from the table.

Hope i am clear with my problem statement.

Comment: Since your query seems to be right what is your problem? don't you get the desired result? The trick is what you have used '(@a is null or field = @a)'

Comment: @RezaRahmati: yes i am not getting the desired result, if i pass null value.

Comment: That should work.  Show how you pass a null value.

Comment: Since you seem to be using the NOLOCK hint quite liberally I will just leave this here for you peruse. It is important you understand what that hint really means (hint...it is not a magic go fast button). http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your conditions filter the data twice with the same condition in case both values are not null. I would write like this:

```
 WHERE (@ZipCodeOrigin IS NULL AND @ZipCodeDestination IS Null)  OR CA.ZipCode IN (@ZipCodeOrigin, @ZipCodeDestination))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to programatically build the query using simple concatenation, then simply not concatenate the condition on ZipCodeOrigin when it's null.

If you have to stick with prepared statements, the solution would be to create 3 more prepared statements, one without the condition on ZipCodeOrigin, another without the condition on ZipCodeDestination and another without both conditions altogether (and without the WHERE clause).

Ahother nasty solution is to use LIKE and if ZipCodeOrigin is null, then make it "%" to match everything.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition like to:

```
   WHERE CA.ZipCode  = ( Case When @ZipCodeOrigin IS Null Then CA.ZipCode Else                       @ZipCodeOrigin END)
      Or  CA.ZipCode = ( Case When @ZipCodeDestination IS Null Then CA.ZipCode Else @ZipCodeDestination END)
```